# Display DIV within certain time

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the start time and end time in MYSQL database. It is a datetype type. How do I display my DIV within the time stated in database? Any hints?

Here's how the start time and end time are stored in the database.

```
2013-12-10 01:40:00 | 2013-12-10 13:40:00
```

Comment: You might be looking for a Javascript solution instead. `setTimeout()` will help.

Comment: @castis I have tried using if..else but got lost halfway .

Comment: show us the code you've tried using.

Comment: Maybe you meant the difference between the timestamps ? How about "select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date2)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date1) as diff_in_seconds from table" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a div with the id of `div1`. You set its `visibility:hidden` or `display:none` in your CSS. You include the jQuery library (because the example code I give you will be using that), preferably in `<head>`.

In your PHP, first you have to query the time from the database.
Then you must use JavaScript `setTimeout()` function for timing. If you pass the time parameter, it must be in milliseconds, here's the full "manual": [manual](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

It will be something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
setTimeout(function(){$('#div1').show();},3000); 
});
```

3000 means 3000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Run mysql query which gets results if time mathces columns. Example query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CURTIME() BETWEEN starttime AND endtime
```

If query returns true, then you can show the div. On false, current time is not in that range.

```
$q= "SELECT * FROM table WHERE CURTIME() BETWEEN starttime AND endtime;";

$run = // run query here

if ($run) {
    echo '<div>Welcome to my page!</div>'
}
else {
    echo '<div>Access denied!</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the current time with the times in your database.  PHP provides a couple of different ways to do this.  For example, you can use strtotime (http://php.net/strtotime):

```
/**
 *  Convert times to unix timestamp
 */
$time = strtotime('2013-12-10 10:40:00');
$start = strtotime('2013-12-10 01:40:00');
$end = strtotime('2013-12-10 13:40:00');

if ( $time >= $start && $time <= $end ) {
    /**
     *  We are between the two times, so display the div.
     */
    ?>
    <div>Blah blah blah</div>
    <?php
}
```

Note that in my example I manually define $time.  For a dynamic page, you would use the following to get the current time, in Unix timestamp form.

```
$time = time();
```

PHP also has a datetime class that will do the same thing (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
<script language="javascript">   
    // get time diff in milliseconds between server endDate
    // and the client-side browser's time
    var timeDiff = new Date() - <?php echo $myDBEndDate ?>;

    // hide in X amount of milliseconds
    if (timeDiff > 0) { // check if positive (in future) number
        setTimeOut(function() {
            $('#myDiv').hide();
        },timeDiff);
    } else 
        $('#myDiv').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Or just in PHP and MySQL (but will only hide the DIV if page reloaded, not live)

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE startDate <= Now() AND endDate >= Now();

if ($rowCount > 0) {
    echo '<div></div>';
}
```